# Jenkinsfile: how to concatenate a variable name for the if statement?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

```
def flag_prod1 = true
def flag_prod2 = false

def prods = [
    'prod1',
    'prod2'
]

pipeline
{
    agent { label "j" }

    stages
    {
        stage('Trigger')
        {
            steps
            {
                script
                {
                    prods.each
                    { prd ->
                        stage("stage $prd")
                        {
                                if (flag_${prd})
                                {
                                     echo "Do something with $prd..."
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `if` statement does not work: `if (flag_${prd})`.
What should be the syntax of the if statement where part of the variable name needs to be taken from the other variable name?

Comment: why not to declare known variable with all possible flags like `def flag = [prod1: true, prod2: false ]` and check the value: `if( flag[prd] ) {...}`

Comment: will try. not sure about the syntax...

Comment: also, how do I loop through such a statement?

Answer (score 0):

why not to declare known variable with all possible flags like this:

```js
def prods = [
    'prod1',
    'prod2'
]
def flags = [
    prod1: true,
    prod1: false,
]


prods.each{prd->
    if( flags[prd] ){
        //do something
    }
}
```

or you could try to define all in one:

```js
def prods = [
    prod1: [
        flag: true
    ],
    prod2: [
        flag: false
    ]
]

for(prd in prods){
    if( prd.flag ){
        //do smth
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works (using iterator key/value, and `toBoolean()` conversion):

```
def jobs = [
    'prod1': true,
    'prod2': false
]

pipeline
{
    agent { label "j" }

    stages
    {
        stage('Trigger')
        {
            steps
            {
                script
                {
                    jobs.each
                    {
                        if ("$it.value".toBoolean())
                        {
                            stage("Stage $it.key")
                            {
                                echo "Do something..." 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```